# parse-server-example on heroku "Cannot get /parse"

Tags: heroku, github, parse-server

Deployed the parse-server-example on heroku using 'Deploy on Heroku' button from github page. Left the default value for PARSE_MOUNT, and updated SERVER_URL config variables.

And going to "https://myapp.herokuapp.com/parse" says "Cannot get /parse" - 404

However, using the curl example to create a GameScore object works fine. Since /parse can't be reachable, the app is not shown in the parse-dashboard (deployed separately on heroku).

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Raj

Comment: You're saying you set the values for PARSE_MOUNT and SERVER_URL in heroku?  Under Settings/Config Variables?  What did you set them to?

Comment: PARSE_MOUNT = /parse, SERVER_URL=http://myapp.herokuapp.com/parse